# Django url parameters prevent download exported excel file

Tags: python, django, excel

I have a url like this: " http://localhost:8001/browse/4/766821590082433/"
and when i click the button to download excel file my url gets : "http://localhost:8001/browse/4/766821590082433//export/xls/".
In my urls.py

url(r'export/xls/$', main.export_users_xls, name='export_users_xls')

but when I pass any other url params like : "http://localhost:8001/browse/4/766821590082433/?earliest=2018-01-10&latest=2018-01-17" I cant download the excel file
and url gets updated to : http://localhost:8001/browse/4/766821590082433/?earliest=2018-01-10&latest=2018-01-17/export/xls/

the error I get is unconverted data remains: /export/xls/

Any idea how to fix this in order to download excel data even when url has parameters.

Comment: Can you add the entire error stack trace

Comment: ValueError at /browse/4/766821590082433/
unconverted data remains: /export/xls/
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8001/browse/4/766821590082433/?earliest=2018-01-10&latest=2018-01-17/export/xls/
Django Version: 1.11.5
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: 
unconverted data remains: /export/xls/

Comment: Your button url has two slashes before export, can you correct that and try again

Comment: actually with this url works "http://localhost:8001/browse/4/766821590082433//export/xls/"    I can download excel file

Comment: You are appending /export/xls/ after your url params, can you show (the code) how you are appending "/export/xls/" to the url

Comment: Please provide the code that doesn't work. Where does the combined url for your button come from?

Comment: <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href=" {{ request.build_absolute_uri }}{% url 'App:export_users_xls' %}">
              <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Download Excel/CSV
            </a>

Comment: @at14 any idea?